# MacOS: Mongodb Code 100

Tags: mongodb, macos, filesystems

```
[shutting down with code 100][1]
```

I'm learning to program through a tutorial on stack social and I'm having a problem with getting the ability to running MongoDB. I have looked at the other similar problems and can't seem to figure out what it is that I am doing wrong or what it is I need to do to fix these issues. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post full logs of mongodb? From /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log?

Comment: I enter the prompt in the terminal and receive "no such file or directory"

Comment: @EddisonTorres can you try starting the database with `sudo` before it, as your problem may be that you aren't giving mongodb permission to write files